# SuiteCommerce Advanced: Product Sharing Feature Not Working, OG Meta Tag in Shopping.ssp

Tags: netsuite, meta-tags, suitecommerce

1. We are using SCA's default feature to Share Product's details on Social Platform.
2. SCA's and Open Graph Protocol's  Documentation says to get the product  title, description, image, url, will require meta tags on html page.
3. We tried configuring all require meta tags and it is coming under  of element(to view this you need to open console and in Element tab under head tag), but We are not able to see Image and Description on Social Platform after sharing the product url. It only gives us product url.

**4. If you view source on product details page, you will not see any configured meta tags there(og tags), we thought this could be the reason. as Ptoduct details page comes under Shopping ssp, We tried adding heard coded meta tags in shopping.ssp file it self, That works for us.**

5. But the question here is that, We will require actual product image, description, title on shopping.ssp, how would we can get that on shopping.spp file.
6. Or us there any way get the meta tags working with the default feature.

How I can add meta tags in shopping.ssp file, or how to get item details in shopping.ssp file.

Answer (score 0):

Which social platform are you trying to use? Facebook has a resource to trouble shoot the implementation at https://developers.facebook.com/.

One thing we discovered is that the URL for the image has to match exactly, so because we were using a folder titled "item images", our images were not showing up because of the space between the two words.

There's also more information at the developer's site: 
https://developers.suitecommerce.com/